# Import data from .csv file to HTML Table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, csv

I have saved excel file as .csv know I want to import that data into HTML table

e.g. the data in the .csv file is as

```
Name, Father's Name, Roll No., Attendance
abc,xyz,11011519-059,P
abs,ijk,11011519-007,A
```

This code is working fine. It reads data successfully from .csv or .txt file but my problem is that I want that data in HTML Table. Can you please provide a simple solution which I can implement on this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Read File (via User Input selection)</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var reader; //GLOBAL File Reader object for demo purpose only

        /**
         * Check for the various File API support.
         */
        function checkFileAPI() {
            if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
                reader = new FileReader();
                return true;
            } else {
                alert('The File APIs are not fully supported by your browser. Fallback required.');
                return false;
            }
        }

        /**
         * read text input
         */
        function readText(filePath) {
            var output = ""; //placeholder for text output
            if (filePath.files && filePath.files[0]) {
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    output = e.target.result;
                    displayContents(output);
                };//end onload()
                reader.readAsText(filePath.files[0]);
            }//end if html5 filelist support
                        else { //this is where you could fallback to Java Applet, Flash or similar
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * display content using a basic HTML replacement
         */
        function displayContents(txt) {
            var el = document.getElementById('main');
            el.innerHTML = txt; //display output in DOM
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function makeTable ( csv ) {

    var rows = csv.split('\n'),
    table = document.createElement('table'),
    tr = null, td = null,
    tds = null;

    for ( var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++ ) {
        tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tds = rows[i].split(',');
        for ( var j = 0; j < tds.length; j++ ) {
           td = document.createElement('td');
           td.innerHTML = tds[j];
           tr.appendChild(td);
        }
        table.appendChild(tr);
    }

    document.appendChild(table);

}
```

Comment: There is no output shown in the browser. I think I am missing something.

Comment: FYI, this won't work on more than the most basic CSV files.  If a cell has spaces, there will be quotation marks everywhere.  If a cell has a comma in the middle, it will split into two table cells.